# How to get rid of timeout errors when publishing Iot Edge solution?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, azure-iot-edge

I'm using VSCode for IotEdge Development. Using "Build and Push Iot Edge solution" worked just fine for some time but all of a sudden the docker containers cannot be pushed to the cloud anymore. I get the following error:

> Get https://[hidden].azurecr.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while
>   waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
>   headers)

What do I have to do to make it work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably some problem with docker running on your development machine. After restarting docker (e.g. by right clicking on the Taskbar icon and selecting "**Restart...**") you should be able to publish your solution again.